# How to hide an application icon from launcher AND interact with it

Tags: android

I have an app and another one that extends the functionality of another one. I'm using `startActivityForResult` to send an Intent from the main app to the other one to check for the presence and get a check value back, but I also want to give to the user the possibility to hide the icon from the launcher. The problem is that if the icon is hid the Intent thinks that the app is not installed. How can I fix this?

**How I check the presence of pro app**

```
if (!ISPRO) {
        Log.d("ProApp", "Check for existence of pro app");

        Intent pro_app = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        pro_app.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("my.app.pro/my.app.pro.Index"));
        pro_app.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        pro_app.putExtra("my.app.check_code",
                "thisIsMyCheckCode");

        try {
            startActivityForResult(pro_app, 0);
            Log.d("ProApp", "startActivityForResult started");
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.w("ProApp", "WARNING! The pro app doesn't exist");
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
        Log.d("ProApp","Pro functions unlocked");
        ISPRO = true;
    }
}
```

**How I send back the check value to main app**

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String check_Code = new String("");

    if (bundle != null)
        check_Code = bundle.getString("my.app.check_code");

    if (check_Code.equals("thisIsMyCheckCode")) {
        Intent retcode = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, retcode);
        finish();
    }
```

**How I hide the icon of pro app**

```
    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user370305 If I remove those permissions it crashes: `09-06 13:26:10.604: E/AndroidRuntime(9790): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=my.app.pro/.Index (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{417bc658 9790:my.app/u0a74} (pid=9790, uid=10074) not exported from uid 10155`

Comment: Basically, if you removed this line `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` from Activity tag then the activity is not appear on device Launcher.

Comment: "then the activity is not appear on device Launcher." : I don't want it to appear in the Launcher. And removing those lines it doesn't apper, but when I'm starting my main application (and it checks for the hidden one) it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are causing your own problem, from your own code. You have:

```
    Intent pro_app = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    pro_app.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("my.app.pro/my.app.pro.Index"));
    pro_app.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
```

This code says "this activity **MUST** be in the launcher". Hence, you cannot complain when that code crashes if that activity is not in the launcher.

Use a different `<intent-filter>` and a matching `Intent` to call out to this plugin. Consider using a signature-level custom permission if the plugin should only be used by your main app and not by other apps.

Comment: You're right, I was totally missing that. +1 for you, as soon as I can I'll try to fix it as you suggested!

Comment: The problem is that if an application is missing from the launcher it can't be called by another one. I have to find a workaround for this..

Comment: @Mangusto: "The problem is that if an application is missing from the launcher it can't be called by another one" -- sorry, but I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @CommonsWare: please have a look at my answer and correct me if I am wrong anywhere except the signature level permission concept which I haven't implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new intent-filter for your application that should be hidden from the launcher (and remove intent-filter for launcher). Then in your first application create an intent to launch the created intent-filter.

Why do you need to have separate applications? To my point of view, it's easier to have the second activity in your application and to run it using explicit intent.

Answer (score 0):

As per the response by `CommonsWare`,I have shown a sample code here to clear the doubt of how to use different `<intent-filter>` and a matching `Intent` to call out to the plugin.

**How I check the presence of pro app**

```
if (!ISPRO) {
        Log.d("ProApp", "Check for existence of pro app");

        Intent pro_app = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        pro_app.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("my.app.pro/my.app.pro.Index"));
//change has been made in next line
        pro_app.addCategory("android.intent.startUpPro");
        pro_app.putExtra("my.app.check_code",
                "thisIsMyCheckCode");

        try {
            startActivityForResult(pro_app, 0);
            Log.d("ProApp", "startActivityForResult started");
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.w("ProApp", "WARNING! The pro app doesn't exist");
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
        Log.d("ProApp","Pro functions unlocked");
        ISPRO = true;
    }
}
```

**How I hide the icon of pro app**

```
//root package declaration

package="my.app.pro"



//activity declaration

     <activity
    android:name="my.app.pro.Index"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.startUpPro" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I hope it will be helpful !!